# Ionic 3 Error : when command run ionic cordova run android

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

ionic 3 Error : when commend run

> cordova platform add android --save
>   **× Running command - failed!
>   [WARN] Platform already added. Saving platforms to config.xml.**
>   Platform android is not installed! Would you like to install it? (Y/n)

and when i try run

> cordova run android shown 
>   Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

**Step 1**: Remove android platform

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

**Step 2**:check  **config.xml** if android platform array is there, if it is still there remove it.

**Step 3**: Add android platform again

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

**Step 4** : **Run** ionic on android

```
ionic cordova run android -l -c
```

**step 5** : genrate resource files for platform details [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-resources)

ionic cordova resources android

Comment: Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Comment: run this cmd **ionic cordova resources android**

Comment: when i add android platform by commend on step3                             × Running command - failed!
[ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2

Comment: and when run and genrate resource file by commend step 5                  √ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!

? Platform android not detected. Would you like to install it? Yes  (same error × Running command - failed!
[WARN] Platform already added. Saving platforms to config.xml.)

Comment: Try step 1,step2 and then  Try ionic Cordova platform add android@6.4.0 , step-5

Comment: same thing [ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@6.4.0  and Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Comment: 1. add platform 2. generate resources 3 . run android make sure you have the correct file size of icon.png 1024*1024px and splash.png 2732*2732px

Answer (score 0):

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Platform android is not installed! Would you like to install it? (Y/n) press **Y**

Please **remove** any **preference** with portrait/landscape from your **config.xml** file **before adding platform**.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to run the command:

```
ionic cordova resources android
```

It creates all the various size images based of a default you supply, adding lines to **config.xml** for build to use later in generation of the APK.

More info on the size can be obtained [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-resources).

- icon.png 1024px x1024px - you supply this.
- splash.png 2732px x 2732px

> The source image for icons should ideally be at least 1024×1024px and
>   located at **resources/icon.png**. The source image for splash screens
>   should ideally be at least 2732×2732px and located at
>   **resources/splash.png**.

...

---

Then follow up with the build:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

As others have indicated it may be prudent to [remove/add platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-platform) again to be sure.

1. `ionic cordova platform rm android`
2. `ionic cordova resources android`
3. `ionic cordova platform add android`

Android Studio:

- Build > Generate Signed APK
- Next
- Keystore password - supply it.
- Next
- Finish
- click locate in notification
  copy app-release-apk to wherever.

If you continue to have issues. Run:

```
ionic info
```

**And paste output into your question as well.**

---

**UPDATED to reflect comments below:**

*I would presume your **config.xml** is somehow hosed*.

There is a section in it which associates icon and splashscreen.

This is what I have in mine for the android platform part.

```
<platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
```

This part gets injected into the code by the

```
ionic cordova resources android
```

If you have src locations that don't relate to real artwork of icons/splashscreens then you are likely to get the error.
Try manually deleting everything between:

```
<platform name="android">
 ....
</platform><!-- The one relating to android! -->
```

Then rerun from the top until the update section.

If all else fails, there may be more issues with the config.xml, in which case you could take more drastic actions...

1. It may be prudent to host your **config.xml** somewhere and link it in the original question rather than comments first though. Somewhere like Googledocs perhaps first.

If I am not around later to answer...

2. You could try creating a new *scratch* project just to get a clean config.xml.
3. If you have many cordova plugins for native functionality, add those to your project with the [ionic cli](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-plugin) too to update config.xml appropriately.
   For example.

---

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@latestcordova-plugin-inappbrowser@latest
```

This incidentally adds these nodes to the config.xml

```
<plugin name="..." spec="..." />
```

4. manually update these again too.

   - widget id property - e.g. *com.yourdomain.yourappname*
   - name
   - description
   - author
5. In the meantime, at the os level delete the platforms folder from your original app project folder,
6. then  rename config.xml to config-old.xml in the original project
7. and copy over the config.xml from the scratch project
8. Then try the whole sequence of steps I have described above again (from the top until the update, returning to step 9 if all is ok at end.
9. Delete the *scratch project* folder if everything works.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: when run ionic cordova resources android ask me to install android platform and when enter yes (× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2

        Adding android project...
        Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Android project created with cordova-android@6.2.3
        Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Comment: and this ionic info:    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:
    Node : v6.16.0
    npm  : 4.6.1
    OS   : Windows 10
Misc:
    backend : pro

Answer (score 0):

on your xml config you should specify the engine accordingly

```
<engine name="android" spec="7.1.4" />
```